# Is there a monero-wallet-rpc call that can sign/verify a message?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, messagesigning

I was wondering if there is such a call in the code, which has not been documented yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the "*sign*" RPC which takes a "*data*" parameter (string), and the "*verify*" RPC which takes "*data*", "*address*" and "*signature*" parameters (strings).